# How to fix missy git commits

Tags: git, github, version-control

I fork one project from github, but because i had some problem with the proxy config of my job a use commits for any modification, so i have a lots of commits like "change sql fix 1", "change sql fix 2", so i made one pull request and is hard to understand what happen in my project, so i want to ***remake*** this kind of commits, i was reading about git rebase, but i dont get any example to make this kind of change.

Is not only commits, i syncronized with the main project some time, so i'm lost about how to do this changes.

So my question, is possible to do this? get commit from c to m and make one commits c-m, this way the person can read and accept my changes.

Example of my git

```
(I)-->(A)--->(B)--->(B1)----->(B2)----->(C)-->(D)-->(D1)-->(D2)-->(E)-->(E1)-->(F)
                                        /                                      /
(I)-->(some commits byt the cominity)->/--------------->(other commits)------>/
```

What i want to get

```
(I)-->(A)------------->(B')------------>(C)-------->(D')---------------->(E')-->(F)
                                        /                                      /
(I)-->(some commits byt the cominity)->/--------------->(other commits)------>/
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do an interactive rebase here

```
git rebase -i (hash of (A)-commit)
```

Comment: So, when you start interactive rebase, you will see list of commits to change, starting from commit A. Now you can do anything with commits from A to F. As far as I understand, you want to squash some commits into one, so select (squash) for commits you want to include into another commit (i.e B1, B2, D1, D2, E1). 
I do not know which tool you are using for git, in git console you just need to change "pick" to "s" in strings with B1 B2 D1 D2 E1 commits.